# Configure internal load balancer for web/worker roles

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to figure out how to configure azure ILB (internal load balancer) for web/worker roles within a cloud service.
I found documentation for PS scripting with Add-AzureEndpoint which relate to VMs, and I didn't found how to configure it to worker role.
The main issue is - how to configure it to all role instances. shall I do it for each instance separately? so when ever I will change the number of instances I will have to reconfigure it?

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 2):

OK, just found that for web/worker roles we don't need any PS scripting. Just need to update the service configuration & definition files as mention on [this blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/04/announcing-release-of-visual-studio-2013-update-3-and-azure-sdk-2-4/), under the: *Cloud Services: New Networking Capabilities in the Service Model* section.